# Specific exception catch blocks does not work when throwing Exception inside Invoked method

Tags: c#

In the code below, I have a catch block for System.UnauthorizedAccessException class exception.

```
           try
            {

                var type = message.Form.GetObjTypeOf(typeof(BaseEntity));  

                MethodInfo updateFormStatusMethod = typeof(IFormService).GetMethod("UpdateFormStatus");
                MethodInfo generic = updateFormStatusMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
                var result = (bool)generic.Invoke(performanceformService, new object[] { message });
             // I throw new System.UnauthorizedAccessException() inside 'UpdateFormStatus' method

            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
               // I'm waiting to get 'UnauthorizedAccessException' here
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
               //But I get it here
            }
```

I'm waiting to get 'UnauthorizedAccessException' in specific catch block but I get it in general catch block.

Comment: Can you show us output of  `typeof(ex).AssemblyQualifiedName` from generic catch block?

Comment: @cassandrad "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"

Comment: Does `ex.InnerException` has value? Is that `UnauthorizedAccessException`?

Comment: @cassandrad Yes inner exception message is UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: Then you can use this: `catch (TargetInvocationException ex) when (ex.InnerException is UnauthorizedAccessException)`. The thing is that any invocation of a method that's constructed with reflection will create `TargetInvocationException` if anything bad happens, and in the `InnerException` will be the root problem. However, `InnerException` will not always be non-empty. Sometimes when the root cause in the invocation itself, there will be no `InnerException`. So probably you have to handle that case as well.

Comment: @cassandrad Ok. I will check for type of Exception and show customized message.Thanks